# Why PUT is no side effect?

Tags: javascript, http, put

The difference between PUT and POST is that PUT is idempotent: calling it once or several times successively has the same effect (that is no side effect), whereas successive identical POST requests may have additional effects, akin to placing an order several times.                  (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)

I understand the no side effect is there is no impact on server resources. so why PUT is no side effect?

I googled but didn't get an answer

Comment: The "no side effect" is a *promise*, so it's up to the implementor to actually prevent a side effect.

Comment: `PUT` usually means update existing object in API, so calling it multiple times _should_ result in same outcome every time (except first call if original object is different)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can understand it as a "guide".

PUT is **designed** to be an *idempotent* method.  So when other developers see an PUT API, they can expect that calling it multiple times will have the same effect.

But whether it is truly "no side effect" depends on the website/API implementation